# Using "Some " vs. Generic Nouns

Tags: adverbs, determiners

> To detect the boundaries of the segments, we may use **[some]** text and visual signals as we scan the page top-down or bottom-up.

By "we" I mean "we as human"

Do I need that "some"? Because I feel, using "some" I mean *a number of them are used in detecting the segment boundaries*. However, if I don't use it, I may imply a generic term for ***text and visual signals***. Right? Which is more usual? I feel English tend to use generic nouns in such cases.

Comment: It's not the *some* but the *by means of* that sounds wrong...

Comment: @Stephie Please check my update

Comment: Sounds like a good alternative to me.

Comment: Please do not use StackExchange as a scratchboard for writing a document.
The math stack exchange strongly discourages writing problems just to get help with answering it.
In other words, although we are happy to help, don't make us write your paper for you.

Comment: @theREALyumdub Ok, I try to bring more general examples, but whenever I do, people ask me for the exact problem and context. Also, if you note I use general titles and explain my question generally, because they are things which happen to me in most of the times, not in writing a specific paper!.

Comment: You are correct that you are using the site appropriately. I was bringing it up because I do not want to see the site become a collection of half written papers, and if you need help we are happy to help.

Comment: @theREALyumdub I just edit the title of the question to say what is my exact problem.

Answer (score 1):

**No**

This sounds like a technical document and "some" sounds out of place to me.

However, in your first sentence, it sounds like you use `text and visual signals` to `scan` the page, which isn't the case. `by means of` should be a complement of `detect`.

Even if you recast the sentence to more clearly identify `by means of` as complement to `detect`, "some" would still be out of place.

Your second sentence is much better.